# Best way to convince managers importance of typography

Tags: typography

Most designers know that typography has a big influence on design and, more importantly, readability (which is a big part of ux). But consumers (as well as managers and business leads) don't know this unless they have been told so or compare good typography with bad typography.

How do you convince your manager/coworker developers as a user experience specialists?

Comment: There is a lot more to the users experience than typography.    As user experience specialist if you want the attention of manager / coworker / developers then come to the table with more than typography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The best way is to **show them**.

Take a screenshot of the tool itself and redesign it using properly treated Typography so they can see the difference. You can present your case with "Before" and "After" slides. In my experience because I like to advocate good design, sometimes will do this just for the heck of it because some bad designs look so gawd-awful.

You can also ask if you can run an A/B test or do a quick hallway test to ask users which version provides a more positive experience for them. You will end up with more measurable results that you can bring forward to your team.

You can also show them other successful companies who maintain great Typography. Providing case studies that show numbers can further your cause.

**Managers still not convinced? Here are some more articles:**

> When done right, it can trigger the right emotion, mood, and even action required to get a visitor to convert.

Read More: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/how-typography-affects-conversions/

This Kissmetrics article displays a **case study of an experiment done by the New York Times**:

http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/08/08/hear-all-ye-people-hearken-o-earth/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0

> Typography plays an important role in influencing people’s decisions.
>   Read More: http://blog.crowdspring.com/2014/05/how-typography-affects-conversions-and-sales/
>
> Can Typography Impact Our Judgement? Yes.

Read More: http://conversionxl.com/the-effects-of-typography-on-user-experience-conversions/

Comment: No prob. If you like this, you can also mark it as the "right answer" for future readers. :)

Comment: Combine misleading graphs, lots of anecdotes, no mentions of effect sizes, citing experts opinions outside of context, lack of reference that can be followed, and abuse of statistics hidden in plain sight, and you can convince people of anything. I read all the articles you mentioned and I think they all provide very poor evidence for their claims.

Comment: I came reading the articles to find how much the effect of poor typography is to believability of an article or conversion rate, which is probably what most marketers would be concerned about. While most of the articles claims that typography affects these (and I don't doubt that poor typography could hurt these factors), none of  articles mentioned how large the effect actually is.

Comment: @LieRyan Great feedback. The focus of the OP question was more regarding how to phrase its importance for Managers and Developers who may be apathetic towards Typography. While I do not know his/her company's industry I do know most managers concern themselves with the Bottom Line in the form of Conversions or actual repeat product usage. re: impact - I was not able to locate specific studies that address how large the effect is. I will definitely update the post when I come across something to that effect.

Comment: I have linked Typography with how it effects one's psychology and the impact of providing a positive or negative experience with the product as a case study. However, this may be more challenging if the OP's manager/developer has the "If it ain't broke don't fix it" mentality.

Comment: Both of your feedback and resources have provide me with great insight and points to further deal with external minds those have less experience in design field.

Answer (score 2):

Use examples.

**First create an artificial "extreme" example with an identical passage of text.**

Lay the first out to be as unreadable as you can... pick a fancy display font set to a small size, make line space very wide, reduce line spacing and decrease contrast of text vs background (e.g. light gray font on white bg).

Lay the second at the same font size with a web optimized san serif font using techniques to enhance readability.

**Then show an "in situ" example.**

Take something from your project that you feel requires work. Clean it up. Then do a before and after comparison. Show them those and point out what you did and how did helped readability.

**Wrap up with the benefits and costs**

Then you close up with how you feel improving readability will help users with their workflow etc. Might want to point out how much time it took you to fix up the "in situ" example. How does it translate to effort if the team does it everywhere.

Then you can field additional questions if they have any.

Good luck with it. Typography is an important part of design. :)